# Java-Sorting a 2-D array quickly

Tags: java, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a 2D string array consisting of values like as

```
{ "Home","0.1256784"  
 "Contact","-0.56789"  
 "Refer","1.36589"  
 "Next","3.678456" }
```

I have to sort the array based upon the second element(double value) and obtain a result such as like

```
{"Contact","-0.56789"  
 "Home","0.1256784"  
 "Refer","1.36589"  
 "Next","3.678456" }
```

I have used some bubble sort code to sort it and it works, but and i have to know how can i make the sorting more efficient than my one in faster manner.I tried some code posted previously for the questions related to mine but i can't get the task done.
My Code:

```
String tt="",tk="";
for(int i=1;i<myarray.length;i++)
 {  
for(int j=1;j<myarray.length-1;j++)
       {
       if(Double.parseDouble(myarray[i][1])<Double.parseDouble(myarray[j][1]))
            {
                    tk=myarray[i][1];  
                    tt=myarray[i][0];  
                    myarray[i][1]=myarray[j][1];  
                    myarray[i][0]=myarray[j][0];  
                    myarray[j][1]=myarray;  
                    myarray[j][0]=myarray;  


            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: try merge sort it runs in O(n log n) as opposed to O(n^2) like bubble sort: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Sort2D {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    String ss[][] = { 
      {"Home", "0.1256784"},
      {"Contact", "-0.56789"},
      {"Refer", "1.36589"},
      {"Next", "3.678456"}
    };
    Arrays.sort(ss, new Comparator<String[]>() {
      public int compare(String[] s1, String[] s2) {
        double d1 = Double.parseDouble(s1[1]);
        double d2 = Double.parseDouble(s2[1]);
        return Double.compare(d1, d2);
      }
    });
    for (String[] s : ss) {
      System.out.println(s[0] + ": " + s[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why are you overriding equals? other than that solution looks good +1

Comment: Thanks for th e reply.I tried the above code and when i run the code some NullPointerException is thrown.It occurs in the line 'Arrays.sort(ss, new Comparator<String[]>()'

Comment: @Aly - good catch, I removed the "equals" override; I added it because it appears in the `Comparator` interface but it is not needed for this simple example because `Object` provides a default implementation.

Comment: @Naveen - this code compiles and runs on its own, you'll have to fit it into your own code structure somehow; I only demonstrated the part you asked about.

Comment: I got it worked.The error i made was that i started the array from ss[1][1] instaed of ss[0][1].So it reported NullpointerException on reading ss[0][1].Thanks a lot maerics..

Answer (score 1):

If it's a 2d array you can use `Array.sort(String[], Comparator<String[]> comparator)` and pass a custom comparator, which compares the 2nd element of the sub array.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Arrays.sortsort(Object[] a, Comparator c)` and let java take care of it. You may find this [link](http://publicmind.in/blog/sorting-2d-array-java/) useful

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach: you could copy the data to a TreeMap (in case all double values are unique) and let the map to the sorting:

```
Map<Double, String> map = new TreeMap<Double, String>();
for (String[] row:myArray) {
   map.put(Double.parseDouble(row[1]), row[1]);
```

The entrysets iterator now returns the values in ascending sort order.